# Fallo con ListView en Fragment

Tags: listview, fragment

Lo que quiero hacer es que listView muestre los datos, tengo el siguiente fallo:

> 05-27 19:26:59.412 13176-13176/com.example.pc.libreta 
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.pc.libreta, PID: 13176
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.pc.libreta/com.example.pc.libreta.Activities.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.pc.libreta.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**MAINACTIVITY**

```
package com.example.pc.libreta.Activities;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.pc.libreta.Fragments.AnadirPersonaFragment;
import com.example.pc.libreta.Fragments.BuscarPersonasFragment;
import com.example.pc.libreta.Fragments.ListadoPersonasFragment;
import com.example.pc.libreta.R;
import com.example.pc.libreta.dataBase.DBHelper;
import com.example.pc.libreta.dataBase.PersonasQuotes;
import com.example.pc.libreta.models.AdaptadorPersonas;
import com.example.pc.libreta.models.Personas;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private ListView mListView;
    private AdaptadorPersonas mAdaptadorPersonas;
    private ArrayList<Personas> datos = new ArrayList<Personas>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setToolbar();

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();


        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);

        setFragmentDefault();


        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PersonasQuotes.PersonasTabla.NOMBRE_TABLA, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PersonasQuotes.PersonasTabla._ID));

            String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PersonasQuotes.PersonasTabla.NOMBRE));
            String apellidos = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PersonasQuotes.PersonasTabla.APELLIDOS));

            datos.add(new Personas(id, nombre, apellidos, null, null, null, null, null,null, null,
                    0, false, null, null));

        }


        //Metemos el Fragmente Listado de Personas en nuestra Activity//





        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetails);

        this.mAdaptadorPersonas = new AdaptadorPersonas(this, R.layout.list_personas_detalle, datos) {
            @Override
            public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
                TextView nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre);
                nombre.setText(((Personas)entrada).getNombre());

                TextView apellidos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewApellidos);
                apellidos.setText(((Personas)entrada).getApellidos());

                TextView fecha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFecha);
                fecha.setText(((Personas)entrada).getFechaNacimiento());
            }
        };
       mListView.setAdapter(mAdaptadorPersonas);










        //MENU DE NAVEGACIÓN//
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                boolean fragmentTransaccion = false;
                Fragment fragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.principal:
                        fragment = new ListadoPersonasFragment();
                        fragmentTransaccion = true;
                        break;

                    case R.id.anadir_personas:
                        fragment = new AnadirPersonaFragment();
                        fragmentTransaccion = true;
                        break;
                    case R.id.buscar_personas:
                        fragment = new BuscarPersonasFragment();
                        fragmentTransaccion = true;
                        break;
                    case R.id.anadir_placa:
                        fragment = new ListadoPersonasFragment();
                        fragmentTransaccion = true;
                        break;

                }
                if (fragmentTransaccion){
                    changeFragment(fragment, item);
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
        //FIN MENU DE NAVEGACIÓN//
    }




    //TOOLBAR//
    private void setToolbar(){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    //FIN TOOLBAR//

    private void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, MenuItem menuItem){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void setFragmentDefault(){
        changeFragment(new  ListadoPersonasFragment(), navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
    }
}
```

**fragment_listado_personas**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example.pc.libretapolicial.Fragments.ListadoPersonasFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

¿Dónde tengo el fallo?

Answer (score 0):

Estás ejecutando el método `setAdapter()` sobre un objeto que no ha sido instanciado y por eso sale un `NullPointerExcepton`

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' 
    on a null object reference at ...
```

En el stack trace te importa ver esta linea que te dice donde fue el fallo:

```
com.example.pc.libreta.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90) at
```

El fallo está en la línea 90 del MainActivity. Debuguealo con breakpoint antes de ejecutar esa linea.

**EDITADO 1**

En base a tu comentario fijate que estás llamando `setFragmentDefault()` antes de inflar el listview. Mové esta línea arriba de `setFragmentDefault()`

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetails);
```

Comment: Ya, si me dice que el  mListView.setAdapter(mAdaptadorPersonas); es null, pero yo cargo el fragment con la listview en setFragmentDefault(); y creo que no debe ser la forma correcta de hacerlo.